# adding DataItems from one page to another in Windows Store Apps?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am creating windows store app in VS2012 c#/xaml using WindowsStore GridApp Template.
And I am using Group and Items pages that this template has.

In Group page I am displaying a list of Rooms - datasource for this are RoomObjects

```
 public class RoomsObject : LivingDataCommon
{
    public RoomsObject()
        : base(String.Empty, String.Empty)
    {

    }



    public RoomsObject(String ID, String title)
        : base(ID, title)
    { }

    //adds Actors to collection of a Room, will be used for Rooms pages
    private ObservableCollection<ActorsObject> _actors = new ObservableCollection<ActorsObject>();
    public ObservableCollection<ActorsObject> Actors
    {
        get { return this._actors; }
    }





}
```

In Item page I am displaying a list of Actors that each Room has - datasource for this are ActorsObjects

```
public class ActorsObject : LivingDataCommon
{
       public ActorsObject()
        : base(String.Empty, String.Empty)
    {
    }

    public ActorsObject(String ID, String title, Boolean homepage,String function, RoomsObject room, double currentValue, ActorsType type, AllActors allactors)
        : base(ID, title)
    {
        this._function = function;
        this._room = room;
        this._currentValue = currentValue;
        this._type = type;
        this._homepage = homepage;
        this._all = allactors;
    }
    //set home page appearance
    private Boolean _homepage = false;
    public static Boolean Homepage = false;




    //sets value of an actor
    private double _currentValue;
    public double CurrentValue
    {
        get { return this._currentValue; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._currentValue, value); }
    }

    //sets and gets function code
    private string _function = string.Empty;
    public string Function
    {
        get { return this._function; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._function, value); }
    }

    //gets room properity
    private RoomsObject _room;
    public RoomsObject Room
    {
        get { return this._room; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._room, value); }
    }

    private ActorsType _type;
    public ActorsType Type
    {
        get { return this._type; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._type, value); }
    }

    private AllActors _all;
    public AllActors All
    {
        get { return this._all; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._all, value); }
    }
}
```

When I select an Actor in Items page my appbar appears and I need on my pinButton to allow that Actor to be displayed at Home.xaml as well.

I am assuming that I should create an empty ObservableCollection an add selected items to it, and then use that collection as data source for Home.xaml, but I am new at c#, I cant get it work..

Please any suggestions, code, or some different ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. just to give you some input. I would probably create a "global" static class for this, which you can access from your entire app (public static class PinnedActors). Within this class you have your static ObservableCollection.

Comment: I am using this class 

`public class AllActors : LivingDataCommon
    { 
    public AllActors()
            : base(String.Empty, String.Empty)
        {
        }

        public AllActors(String ID, String title)
            : base(ID, title)
        { }

        private ObservableCollection<ActorsObject> _AllActors = new ObservableCollection<ActorsObject>();
        public ObservableCollection<ActorsObject> allActors
        {
            get { return this._AllActors; }
        }


    }`

Comment: and this is my button code, but it doesnt add anything 
`private void Button_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           

            AllActors m = new AllActors();
           


            m.allActors.Add((ActorsObject)itemGridView.SelectedItem);
               
            
        }`

Comment: Well, I can't help you if you don't tell me what exactly doesn't work (any exceptions??). Why don't you specify a `set{};` method for `allActors`? Anyway you should be close to a solution.

Comment: there is no exceptions, just when i click on the button, it does not do anything.. I think I need to build observable collection of ActorsObjects that I can access in from anywhere in my App, but how do I do that?